# What is a dynamic typing bug?

Tags: dynamic, types, static

When it comes to programming, I don't hold strong opinions about feature x vs feature y.  I think all have their appropriate uses.

And I'm always reading everything I can about as many programming languages I can get my hands on so that I can pull the best ideas out and compare them all (from Haskell to Lisp to C to Erlang).

But there is something that's been bothering me a little bit, and basically it's that when I've read about comparisons between static and dynamic typing, one downside for dynamic typing is that "bugs" come in because the compiler isn't able to check the type of the variable.

Now, I have plenty of bugs when I program, but I have *never* had a bug due to something like this, and I'm actually having a hard time visualizing what an example of such a bug would be.  Like maybe forgetting you used an integer instead of a string somewhere?  This seems so contrived though...

I program for a hobby, not a living, so perhaps these types of bugs only come in when people with different ways of thinking about things get together.  I'm really just looking for some real-world examples.

Comment: Let's say I give you a function as part of my API that looks like such:  function foo(datablob1, id, args) .  What do you suppose I want you to pass?  Would you guess that id is a String or an Integer?  Would you guess that args is an array?  An array of what?  What is datablob?  What properties might it have?  How might you know in absence of good documentation?

Comment: I normally just look the function up in the documentation.  Is this not how most people do it?

Comment: "In absence of good documentation"

Comment: I saw that -- I just think it's odd that there would not be good documentation.  That could be the explanation for a whole family of bugs not even related to typing.

Comment: In the professional world it is not uncommon to work with systems in-progress that are not at all documented, or legacy code that is poorly documented, and to interface with services that are black boxes to you and which you cannot crack open the source code to see just what was it was intended to consume.  This isn't to say that strong typing solves the problem, but untyped dynamic languages can exacerbate it.

Comment: So in this respect, static typing is a way of preventing a suboptimal system from becoming even more suboptimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example would be when you change a variable from one type to another:

```
setType(String type)
```

Then later you decide to change the type to a more efficient enum:

```
setType(SomeEnum type)
```

When you do that in a strongly typed language, you will get errors wherever `setType` is called. That allows you to fix them quickly and to make sure you didn't miss any. In a dynamic typed language, you won't get such errors and will have to look for these instances by yourself.

Strongly typed languages are also generally faster since they can store data in more efficient structures (since the type is known at compile-type). An example are C arrays versus PHP arrays. C arrays are compact but PHP arrays have a rather big overhead to manage the dynamic data they contain.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point.  So basically anytime you have a lot of code, and you go back and change some of its basic structure, you're probably going to miss a lot of things in other places that need to be fixed.

Comment: After thinking it over a bit, it seems to me that some sort of system could be developed to track these types of mass program changes.  "Try to compile and go through correcting errors" seems kind of messy to me.  Perhaps something that ties variable types into a database and describe their relations.  Does such a system exist?

Comment: Informal documentation almost always is incomplete, out of sync, or even plain wrong in any real system under development.  Types on the other hand are machine-checked bits of documentation.

Comment: Interesting to know, although kind of sad to see that is the case.  Is this situation more common in real-world programming than other jobs? (i.e., I'm a chemical engineer -- and a system without up-to-date documentation and thorough, frequent checks would lead to a disaster).  I mean, I know you have skilled and unskilled employees in every field -- I'm just wondering if there is a higher trend of not keeping documentation current in software development?

Answer (score 2):

@Laurent has answered your question very nicely. I would just like to add that, for example, there's a testing/dynamic-bug-finding tool for JavaScript (a dynamically typed language) called [TypedJS](http://typedjs.com/). It is just designed to prevent bugs that occur due to dynamic programming.

An example bug that TypedJS tries to prevent can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: TypedJS]

Comment: This is interesting.  So it basically serves to catch human mistakes before a product is shipped rather than after the fact?

Comment: @Nick Exactly. (1, 2, 3 so that SO doesn't complain about the length of my comment... :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot that can be said about types and their value for programming. For example, here is a recent article in CACM discussing (among other things) the anecdotical advantages of the advanced type system found in the functional language OCaml:

http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2011/11/138203-ocaml-for-the-masses/

On a more principled note, the first couple of pages in the following classic paper classify kinds of program errors, and explain a few of the basic merits of type systems:

http://www.lucacardelli.name/Papers/TypeSystems.pdf

Since the latter paper is relatively old, let me add two things.

First, there is a difference between a language being typed, and requiring (explicit) type declarations. Some modern languages, especially from the functional camp, have sophisticated type systems that yet don't require you to write down a single type most of the time. All types are inferred by the compiler.

Second, a type system essentially is a logic. A logic that expresses certain properties of a program, which then get checked by the compiler. In principle, there is no limit to how powerful this logic can be made. There are languages whose type systems are powerful enough that you can e.g. express the type of sorted lists, and the type of a sorting function, so that the function only type-checks if it actually is a correct implementation of a sorting algorithm. Obviously, it is immensely useful if the compiler can actually check correctness of your program like that. However, there is a trade-off between expressiveness of a type system and ease of use, so in practice, most mainstream languages end up on the simplistic side. But special domains can benefit from more sophisticated type systems enormously.